# Where can I find Fantasy Pregen Characters?

Tags: savage-worlds, savage-worlds-fantasy

Has anyone done any **Savage World** *Iconic* (1)  Fantasy Characters pregens with all their advances, like [Triple Ace Games' Daring Tales of the Space Lanes Character Pregens](http://tripleacegames.com/Downloads/DaringTalesSpaceLanes/dtosl_pregens.zip) who I can give to player that don't want to manage their characters?

1) ie Pregen examples used in a adventure path

Comment: What do you mean by "iconic"? Is that a "Savage World" game-term or do you mean "iconic" like Conan, Gandalf, Morgana la Fay...

Comment: I mean like Pathfinder Adventures use for there example pregens. That is Characters that have a predefined advancement through a campaign so players can pick them up at any point and just play. The Darling Tales has such a set for the Space Lanes campaign.

Comment: I read this first as "Fantasy Ironic Characters".  Would make a question, I guess.

Comment: Changed title to make clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tommy Brownell has done it on [The Most Unread Blog on the Internet. Ever.](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/)

**Savage Worlds Characters Are All The Same**

- [Introduction](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2010/11/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same.html)
- [Character Creation](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2010/11/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same_25.html)
- [Novice Advances](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2010/11/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same_30.html)
- [Seasoned Advances](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2010/12/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same.html)
- [Veterans Advances](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2010/12/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same_19.html)
- [Hero Advances](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2010/12/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same_26.html)
- [Legendary Advances](http://mostunreadblogever.blogspot.com/2011/01/savage-worlds-characters-are-all-same.html)